# HTML signature in Gmail app

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to set a HTML signature in the Android Gmail app somehow? I set something like

```
<a href="http://myurl">mytitle</a>
```

as a signature but the HTML tags didn't parse.

If you can suggest another app that allows HTML signature that will also be cool.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't work because the app can only sent plain text messages, hence also no HTML signatures.
I don't know of other email apps that support HTML messages.

Comment: Sorry to zombie this post, but I'm drumming up support for a proper fix. Here's where you can upvote the issue (please 'star' it, top left) to help us all get the fix. :) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69060926

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One current work around would be to create a draft in gmail that has the signature and use it in the mobile app.

Comment: It does work. But once I use up this draft from mobile, do I have to create a draft again from PC?

Comment: I would recommend making a good hand full of blanks and see how long they last.  I only use them for certain messages when I want a more professional e-mail.

Comment: I normally attach signature to every mail. Your solution is cool but unfortunately not enough for me :)

Comment: accepted it anyway..

Answer (score 5):

There is an open ticket to the Gmail application team via the android project to address this.  Please vote for the issue if you wish to see html signature support in the native gmail application.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17752

Answer (score 3):

The gmail app does not support html signatures, like you noticed only the actual html code will be sent and displayed.

You may want to try [K9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5mc2NrLms5Il0.) or [TouchDown](https://market.android.com/search?q=touchdown&so=1&c=apps).

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add signature in K9 tbh. However I found out it is a open project on github, hopefully more features will come to it.

Comment: You have to select your account and then settings in order to find signature settings. They exist. Thanks Robby Pond for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Market and get the app [Enhanced Email](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail&hl=en).

This will allow you to do it. It does cost $2.99, but hey I believe its worth it if this guy has support and no one else does.

Comment: I downloaded an apk and tried it. It does work. But for a paid app the interface is not good enough. Also Gmail threads are showed as separate mails.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184194&topic=21372&ctx=topic) for Gmail for mobile browsers.

When you don't use a mobile-specific signature, your desktop email signature from your main Gmail settings will be used.

But, not the Gmail app. Go figure!

Answer (score -2):

The gmail app states that signature can only be in text form- no mention of HTML.

Comment: Where does it state this?

Comment: Under Settings for your account on the app, the signature option states "Append text to messages you send".

Comment: That's not really specific.  Rich text is still text.